# Splitting a column when there is no space between two words

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, split

I have a dataframe with the following column,

```
   Ann
  Intergenic
  exon (ENS, exon 2 of 2)
  promoter-TSS (ENST)
  TTS (ENST0)
  intron (ENST, intron 1 of 1
```

and I am aiming to split the column Ann into Ann1 like this,

```
     Ann    Ann1
  Intergenic Intergenic
  exon (ENS, exon 2 of 2) exon
  promoter-TSS (ENST)    promoter-TSS
  TTS (ENST0)             TTS 
  intron (ENST, intron 1 of 1) intron
```

And so I tried,

```
df["Ann1"]=df['Ann'].apply(lambda x: x.split('\s'))
df["Ann1"]
        [Intergenic]
1        [exon (ENST, exon 2 of 2)]
4             [promoter-TSS (ENST)]
5                      [TTS (ENST)]
6    [intron (ENST, intron 1 of 1)]
```

But it looks like space is not "space " like to split it. Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) (default separator is white space, so can be omit) with `str[0]` for select first list value:

```
df["Ann1"]=df['Ann'].str.split().str[0]
print (df)
                             Ann          Ann1
0                     Intergenic    Intergenic
1        exon (ENS, exon 2 of 2)          exon
2            promoter-TSS (ENST)  promoter-TSS
3                    TTS (ENST0)           TTS
4    intron (ENST, intron 1 of 1        intron
```

Solution with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df["Ann1"]=df['Ann'].str.extract('(\S+)', expand=False)
print (df)
                             Ann          Ann1
0                     Intergenic    Intergenic
1        exon (ENS, exon 2 of 2)          exon
2            promoter-TSS (ENST)  promoter-TSS
3                    TTS (ENST0)           TTS
4    intron (ENST, intron 1 of 1        intron
```

For better performance is posible use `n=1` parameter, thank you [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45418870/splitting-a-column-when-there-is-no-space-between-two-words/45419005?noredirect=1#comment77800428_45419005):

```
df["Ann1"]=df['Ann'].str.split(n=1).str[0]
```

Comment: Soory also I could do it like this,Final['Annotation'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])

Comment: Yes, `Final['Annotation'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])` work also, but failed if some `NaN`. But if no NaN is possible use it.

Comment: You can spare the processor from working too hard by passing the `n=1` parameter to the `split` ensuring that it will only attempt to split on first whitespace.  `df["Ann1"]=df['Ann'].str.split(n=1).str[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`pd.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

I use a regex pattern that extracts two groups.  The first parenthesis grabs the whole string while the second parenthesis grabs the first part of the string that isn't broken by white space.  I then use the parameter `expand=True` to place both groups into there own dataframe columns (otherwise, we would have a `pd.Series` of lists).  Finally, I use the `'?P<name_of_column>'` regex convention to name my resulting columns in one step.

```
df.Ann.str.extract('(?P<Ann>(?P<Ann1>\S*).*)', expand=True)

                           Ann          Ann1
0                   Intergenic    Intergenic
1      exon (ENS, exon 2 of 2)          exon
2          promoter-TSS (ENST)  promoter-TSS
3                  TTS (ENST0)           TTS
4  intron (ENST, intron 1 of 1        intron
```